# Counting comma saperated elements as value in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to count the values ​​separated by commas from the same field with aggregations or any other way?

i.e
JSON

```
{
  "ID":"example.1",
  "Sports":{
    "1":
      {,
      "Football Teams":" Real Madrid, Manchester United, Juventus"
      "Basket Teams":"Chicago Bulls"
        
      },
    "2":
      {
      "Football Teams":"F.C Barcelona, Milan"
      "Basket Teams":"Lakers"
        
      }
  }
}
```

query

```
GET xxx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {
      
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "Sports.1."Football Teams.keyword"
      }}
  }
}
```

Desired Output

```
"aggregations" : {
    "Count" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Real Madrid, Manchester United, Juventus",
          "doc_count" : 3
        }
```

The objective of the query I am looking for is to be able to determine how many values ​​separated by commas a field has.

Comment: It's not clear what you're after... Can you explain in a little bit more details please?

Comment: I have added the query for even though I am aware that it does not work that way to get the value I am looking for.
I hope this way it is better explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a [`value script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_value_script_9) in a `terms` sub-aggregation:

```
GET xxx/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "team.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "team.keyword",
            "script": {
              "source": "/,/.split(_value).length",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The top-level buckets will be the values of the football team and each top-level bucket will have a sub-bucket with the number of tokens, like this:

```
    {
      "key" : "Real Madrid, Manchester United, Juventus",    <-- team name
      "doc_count" : 1,
      "count" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "3",                                     <-- number of teams
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

In order for this to work, you need to add the following line in `elasticsearch.yml` and restart your server:

```
script.painless.regex.enabled: true
```

Comment: Return this error: Regexes are disabled. Set [script.painless.regex.enabled] to [true] in elasticsearch.yaml to allow them. Be careful though, regexes break out of Painless's protection against deep recursion and long loops
How can I enable it?

Comment: Finally I decided to change the structure the JSON before of elasticsearch.
Anyway the answer was very usefull.
Thank you again Val